# Proper Test for Type of Data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, dataset

**Warning:** I have not done any statistical analysis since 2012.

**Problem:** I have a list of lists of lists: Each of the $289$ ($17\times 17$) element is $\{\phi_{j,1},\phi_{j,2},f(\phi_{j,1},\phi_{j,2}),\{s_j\}\}$ where $s_j$ is a set of randomly sampled values for a given input $\phi_{j,1},\phi_{j,2}$. Index $j$ runs from $1$ to $289$. Function $f(\phi_{j,1},\phi_{j,2})$ is the predicted mean of set $s_j$. In the language I'm used to the mean $<s_j>$ is the "observed" value while $f(\phi_{j,1},\phi_{j,2})$ is the "expected" value. It's worth noting that $f$ can equal $0$ for some (actually many) inputs.

If I want to compare the $289$ sampled means $\langle s_j\rangle$ to the predicted means $f(\phi_{j,1},\phi_{j,2})$, **which statistical test do I do?** I'm tempted to use $\chi^2$ but the
"expected" value is often $0$ and I don't know enough to proceed.

**What I have done:** Beyond just toying with the data, I've done a sort of $\chi^2$ test which I'll call $X^2$ because it's kinda like a $\chi^2$ I think except it's divided by "observed" instead of "expected" to avoid divergence from $1/0$.

$$
X^2\equiv\sum_{j=1}^{289}\frac{\left(<s_j>-f\left(\phi_{j,1},\phi_{j,2}\right)\right)^2}{f\left(\phi_{j,1},\phi_{j,2}\right)}
$$

and then I plugged $X^2$ into the following equation with $k=2$ degrees of freedom:
$$
\Gamma\left(\frac{k-1}{2},X^2\right)/\text{ }\Gamma\left(\frac{k-1}{2}\right)\rightarrow \pi^{-1/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2},X^2\right)
$$
which outputs a number that's somehow related to the $p$-value, maybe?

I've also done something similar with
$$
2\sum_{j=1}^{289}\frac{<s_j>-f\left(\phi_{j,1},\phi_{j,2}\right)}{<s_j>+f\left(\phi_{j,1},\phi_{j,2}\right)}
$$
because that's just difference divided by average. However, I'm not sure how to interpret that either! Finally, I messed with the previous equation by putting in absolute values into the variables to take differences and averages in magnitude.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** $\{s_j\}$ is a list of $L$ measurements from a simulated quantum system defined by parameters $\phi_{j,1}$ and $\phi_{j,2}$; there are $289$ different lists of $L$ measurements corresponding to the $289$ different combinations of $\phi_{j,1},\phi_{j,2}$. According to physical theories $f(\phi_{j,1},\phi_{j,2})$ should exactly equal $\langle s_j\rangle$ for a given $\{s_j\}$ in the limit $L\rightarrow\infty$. At the risk of overexplaining there is a second function $v(\phi_{j,1},\phi_{j,2})$ which predicts the variance of set $\{s_j\}$.

Essentially I'm trying to see if the function $f$ is a good fit for the data where data point $j$ is described by $\{\phi_{j,1},\phi_{j,2},\{s_j\}\}$. The data is simulated but we want to analyze it before running in a real quantum system.

Comment: Are both $s_{j}$ and $f$ 17x17 matrices? When you say you want to compare $s_{j}$ and $f$, can you be more explicit about what you want to compare? Do you expect them to have the same average, the same standard deviation, the same number of 0 elements?

Comment: I think I've edited it properly! Thanks.